# What is many:1 and collision in MD5?

Tags: hash, collision-resistance, md5, terminology

This is in reference to [this answer on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4948393/1495539). If you read the first paragraph of the answer, you'll find this line:

> It's always a **many:1** mapping (meaning there will always be collisions) since every function produces a smaller output than it's capable of inputting (If you feed every possible 1mb file into MD5, you'll get a ton of collisions).

What is this many:1 and what are collisions? Does many:1 mean two different inputs would have the same hash outputs?

Answer (score 4):

> Does many:1 mean two different inputs would have the same hash outputs?

Yes. This is a consequence of the [pidgeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle): as MD5 has a much larger number of potential inputs ($2^{2^{64}}$ or so) than outputs ($2^{128}$), some inputs *must* lead to the same output, i.e. collide.

Cryptographic hashes all have this "limitation", because they have a constant output size and allow much larger inputs. However, with good cryptographic hashes (MD5 is very broken in this sense), you have no way of *finding* those collisions. This is called collision resistance and is [one of the properties](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/1174/13625) we require of hashes.