# Is H(k||length||x) a secure MAC construction?

Tags: hash, mac

If $H$ is a typical secure hash function, then [$(k,x) \mapsto H(k \mathbin\| x)$ is not a secure MAC construction](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1070/why-is-hkx-not-a-secure-mac-construction), because given a known plaintext $x_1$ and its MAC $m_1$, an attacker can extend $k \mathbin\| x_1$ to a longer message with the same hash.

Is $(k,x) \mapsto H(k \mathbin\| \mathrm{len}(x) \mathbin\| x)$ (where $\mathrm{len}$ unambiguously encodes the length of $x$) a secure MAC construction? Obviously it's inconvenient because you can't treat $x$ as a stream, but is there a known security weakness, or is this known to be as strong as HMAC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What assumptions do we make of $H$, and what properties do we hope of $H'_k\colon m \mapsto H(k \mathbin\| \operatorname{len}(m) \mathbin\| m)$?  Here are some reasonable choices:

1. $H$ is a random oracle, and we want $H'_k$ to be indifferentiable from a random oracle.  In this case the prefix construction $m \mapsto H(k \mathbin\| m)$ *already* achieves this, so restricting ourselves to those messages that begin an encoding with their own length couldn't possibly change it.
2. $H$ is BLAKE2, SHA-3, or another modern ‘hash function’, and we want $H'_k$ to be a pseudorandom function family.  In this case, $H$ was designed so that $m \mapsto H(k \mathbin\| m)$ is *already* conjectured to be a PRF, so restricting ourselves to those messages that begin an encoding with their own length couldn't possibly change it.  (Also these all have native PRF constructions: keyed BLAKE2, KMAC.  So the point is largely moot.)
3. $H$ is MD5, SHA-1, or another Merkle–Damgård hash function with some modest security properties conjectured of the underlying compression function—whatever properties we need for the favored security claim of HMAC *du jour*.  This is presumably the main case of interest.  The answer is essentially **yes, this is as secure as HMAC with a much simpler proof.**

   - Obviously, there is a generic attack finding an internal collision as described in 1996 by Preneel and van Oorschot in Proposition 4 of the MDx-MAC paper[[1]](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-44750-4_1)—which is exactly the same as for HMAC, and for *any* iterated function, with query cost proportional to the square root of the number of possible intermediate states.<sup>*</sup>
   - *Also* in 1996, Bellare, Canetti, and Krawczyk studied what they called ‘the cascade construction’[[2]](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~mihir/papers/cascade.html), and showed that if $F_k\colon m \mapsto F(k, m)$ is a PRF, then the cascade $$F^*_k\colon (m_1, m_2, \dots, m_n) \mapsto F(F(\dots F(F(k, m_1), m_2) \dots), m_n)$$ is almost a PRF—specifically, $F^*_k$ is indistinguishable from a uniform random function to any adversary that *never queries it for any message that is a prefix of another message*.  $F^*$ is also not quite an application of a Merkle–Damgård function, because the key $k$ has replaced the role of the IV, but it's not a stretch to assume that $k \mapsto F(\mathit{IV}, k)$ is a pseudorandom generator, and $H(k \mathbin\| m) = F^*_{F(\mathit{IV}, k)}(m)$ (modulo fenceposts around block sizes).

     Under these modest assumptions (and with a much simpler proof than anything in the continuing saga of HMAC), the function $m \mapsto H(k \mathbin\| m)$ is almost a PRF in the above sense.  If we apply any prefix-free encoding of messages *before* feeding them to this, then we get a PRF, which by the usual theorem is also a MAC.  And length-delimiting $m \mapsto \operatorname{len}(m) \mathbin\| m$ is an example of a prefix-free encoding.

---

<sub><sup>*</sup> Only for small hash functions like MD5 is this *potentially* a concern—for SHA-256, it is totally unimaginable—but even for MD5 it requires $2^{64}$ queries *to the oracle*, not $2^{64}$ offline computations.  Can your application server handle $2^{64}$ queries before humanity cooks the planet?  I doubt it!  (Hint: Suppose your server takes one *nanosecond* to answer a query. 
 How many years is $2^{64}$ nanoseconds?)</sub>

Answer (score 16):

This construction is not secure. It was proposed in [this paper](http://scholar.google.ca/scholar?cluster=13337249459248979759&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5) in a quick sentence for possibly fixing the insecure secret prefix construction from the other question: $\mathcal{H}(k||m)$. The author then proposes and analyzes an enveloping method: $\mathcal{H}(k_1||x||k_2)$.

An attack involving finding an internal collision applies to $\mathcal{H}(k||\ell_m||m)$. It is a bit complex, but if you are curious, it is "Proposition 4" in [this paper](http://people.scs.carleton.ca/~paulv/papers/Crypto95.pdf) (also see section 4.1, 1st paragraph). The authors also note that the construction involves additional assumptions on the hash function than the standard ones (collision-resistance, (second) preimage resistance). It is not as efficient of a break as the length-extension attacks on the other construction but it is theoretically a break relative to the security of HMAC.

I will also note that "unambiguously" encoding the length could be problematic. For example (using base 10 for readability), if I hash m=08 with length=2  and some k, then a length extension attack may find m=0896346218569465994320 which could be interpreted as length=20 and m=896346218569465994320. One fix to unambiguously delimiting the length from the message is to fix a certain number of bytes for the length, but you now no longer have a MAC that accepts arbitrary-length inputs.

In conclusion, the HMAC construction is very simple, accepts arbitrary length inputs, and does not rely on an encoding scheme to work.

Comment: For the length encoding, one can use 7-bit encoding: you represent the length in base 128. Then each "digit" is encoded as a byte, setting the most significant bit for all bytes except the last. This is what is used to encode OID elements in ASN.1/DER; it has no inherent limit. Of course, realistically, encoding over a fixed-length 128-bit field is sufficient and much simpler.

Comment: As for the complaint that a MAC needs to accept arbitrary length inputs, that's not actually true for existing accepted MACs.  As one example, HMAC-SHA256 is limited to $2^{64}-513$ bits.  I have yet to hear anyone complain about this restriction.

Comment: This answer claims that Proposition 4 in the Preneel–van Oorschot MDx-MAC paper is ‘theoretically a break relative to the security of HMAC’.  This claim is false: the attack in Proposition 4 applies just as well to HMAC.  All HMAC security claims involve a term of $O(q^2/2^b)$, _e.g._ the [original 1996 Bellare–Canetti–Krawczyk paper](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~mihir/papers/hmac.html#kmd5-paper) describes it in terms of  collision resistance (limited to a birthday bound) and the [updated 2006 Bellare paper](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~mihir/papers/hmac-new.html) has $\binom{q}{2}$ in Theorem 4.3.