# What is the proper way to use a client nonce?

Tags: hash, authentication, implementation

I've implemented an API for one of my clients, it relies on *nonces* and a *shared secret*. The structure:

1. Client's Site (**CS**) requests nonce from My App (**MA**), posting their *username*
2. **MA** verifies the *username* is valid, then generates a *nonce* in response

   - The *nonce* is only valid for the given *username* and is only valid for 1 minute.
3. **CS** uses the *nonce* to make a userful API call; the post looks like this:

   - username, nonce (from step 2), cnonce (Generated by **CS**), payload (Useful API call), and hash Which is a sha1 hash of the nonce, payload, shared secret, and the client nonce.
4. **MA** confirms that the nonce is valid for the given username (and then invalidates the nonce for future use), and then uses the shared secret for the given username along with the nonce and provided client nonce to hash the payload and confirm the hash matches the given hash.

   If it matches, it executes the API call specified in the payload.

My question: Am I using the idea of a *cnonce* correctly? I'm having a hard time seeing its usefulness.

Comment: The construction Hash(_nonce_ || _payload_ || _shared secret_ || _cnonce_) is a substandard Message Authentication Code; a safer option is HMAC(_shared secret_, (_cnonce_ || _nonce_ || _payload_) ). See the answer to [this question](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/1186/555)

Comment: What is your goal with these nonces at all?

Comment: @fgrieu thank you, I will switch over to that MAC convention [I have used that style before, but had forgotten about it -.- ]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The client nonce is there to protect the client against a replay attack. Without the client nonce, an attacker could intercept the initial request for a nonce by CS, and respond with an old nonce that the server used previously. Then, the client would use that old nonce and make an API call with it, which the attacker would again intercept, and the attacker would send back the response that the true server had actually sent when the nonce was first used. To sum up, the replay attack is about making the client interact with an old ghost of the server. The client nonce allows the client to make sure that he is talking with a "fresh and alive" server.

A client nonce would not be needed if the client had a local memory large enough to recall all previously used nonces -- the kind of memory which resists across reboots, and can store all nonces for the whole duration of the shared secret life. That's rarely practical.

Comment: The _cnounce_ **could** and **should** be used as suggested in this answer; but it **is not** used in this way in the protocol now described in the question. For now, _cnounce_ seems to protects only against an adversary trying to determine if _shared secret_ has changed.