# How many bytes of data does AES 256 encrypt at one time?

Tags: aes, key-size

Since the block size of AES 256 is 256, how would we calculate the bytes of data AES 256 encrypts at one time?

Comment: There are ways of doing AES in parallel, so you could be doing a bunch of bytes at one time, https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/34740/parallel-file-encryption-and-authentication-for-large-files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AES has always 128-bit block size with 128,192 and 256-bit keyspaces.  Therefore, you can encrypt 16-byte at a time if you are using ECB and CBC modes. By using CTR mode you can encrypt 1-bit to 128-bit.

Some people confuse AES with Rijndael where AES is a variant of the Rijndael. Some old libraries use the Rijndael (see [RijndaelManaged](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rijndaelmanaged)). Rijndael can have 128, 160, 192, 224, and 256-bit block size. Note that these are not standardized, see [FIPS 197](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/fips/nist.fips.197.pdf).

Comment: So both AES 128 and AES 256 encrypt 16 bytes at a time?

Comment: @joshkmartinez  Yes.  128 & 256 refer to the key size, not the block size. The block always remains at 128 bits/16 bytes. One way to look at it, is that the AES block (rectangular) gets deeper, rather than wider.