# Least-weak way to authenticate using only AES ECB/CBC

Tags: aes, authentication, embedded

I have an embedded application that needs to occasionally get secure updates from a server. The only crypto library I have available for the chip is an AES-256 cipher (ECB and CBC, encrypt/decrypt).

Is there any worthwhile way to authenticate the message using only these functions and simple checksums? If I just did something like a 32 bit checksum of the plaintext and appended it before encryption, would that be vulnerable to attack (other than being only 32 bits of protection)?

Answer (score 8):

> Is there any worthwhile way to authenticate the message using only
> these functions and simple checksums?

As usual, of course there is: [AES-CCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CCM_mode)!

AES-CCM basically is CTR mode with a tagged-on CBC-MAC and length prepending. You can implement CTR trivially using your ECB primitive and CBC-MAC shouldn't be too hard to implement given a CBC primitive and direct function access.
If implementig CTR is infeasible, CBC should do the job just as well.
If you want to go fancy (and don't live with length-prepending) you can also go for [AES-EAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EAX_mode) although it's a bit more difficult to implement.

> If I just did something like a 32 bit checksum of the plaintext and
> appended it before encryption, would that be vulnerable to attack
> (other than being only 32 bits of protection)?

No, this is a bad idea. Not only is a checksum usually not safe in the sense that a proper cryptographic hash would be, but also is this composition already insecure as fgrieu explained much better than I ever could in his answer to [*"Why is plain-hash-then-encrypt not a secure MAC?"*](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/16431/23623).

---

<sub>**Relevant standards**: CCM: [RFC 3610](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3610), [NIST SP 800-38C (PDF)](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-38C/SP800-38C_updated-July20_2007.pdf); EAX: [The original specification](http://web.cs.ucdavis.edu/%7Erogaway/papers/eax.html)</sub>

Comment: Thanks, very interesting. Can you elaborate on what you mean by "CBC-MAC shouldn't be too hard to implement given a CBC primitive and direct function access"?

Comment: @Chriszuma, CBC-MAC basically is just CBC over the data (e.g. the ciphertext) with its own key and _maybe_ (depending on the exact variant used) requires applying ECB (=direct function access, you basically have AES at your disposal) once more on the last block.

Comment: EAX mode could also considered; it's CTR mode with AES-CMAC authentication. AES-CMAC is relatively easy to forge from CBC-MAC as used by CCM mode. CCM mode is a packet oriented mode of operation which describes a specific format with some nasty surprises. EAX is a much more flexible AEAD cipher. Of course in the end you can use any authenticated cipher that can be build from AES as single block AES-ECB (without padding) *is* the block cipher. Dare I mention OCB? Guess I just did.