# How to make cookies tamper-proof and secure by using encryption and hash / MAC

Tags: aes, hmac, ctr

Our company has decided to ditch server side sessions in favor of storing authenticated information such as user id and access privilege information in a cookie.

Before everyone jumps up and down about this approach, given that this is a business decision - how would I do this right? The basic need is to prevent user from tampering the cookie to avoid promoted privileges / or pretend to be a different user and also hides the information. Assumption is all systems are running HTTPS hence let's pretend we won't have cookies being hijacked and replayed etc.

I've read [Should we MAC-then-encrypt or encrypt-then-MAC?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/202/should-we-mac-then-encrypt-or-encrypt-then-mac) but I just want to know if this naive approach can work: (plaintext below is my cookie in json format).

```
// where only 1 secret for AES is used
aes-ctr((plaintext || sha2-256(plaintext)) || iv
```

Or do I have to do this?

```
// where 2 secrets are used, one with HMAC and one with AES
let E be: (aes-ctr(plantext) || iv)
then E || hmac (E)
```

Or are both approaches insufficient?

There are a few key difference between the 2 approaches:

1st approach: In the digest part, we are doing the simple sha256 without the use of nonce or key.

2nd approach: We are using HMAC with one key and another key for AES.

Based on my limited understanding, the listed arguments against a plain digest as oppose to HMAC is due to opportunities for length-extension based attacks. However in my case, given I've AESed the digest, there should be no such opportunity.

Other attacks listed in here: http://www.thoughtcrime.org/blog/the-cryptographic-doom-principle/ appears to be applicable for block mode only, where we are using CTR.

Apologies if this question appears naive - I am a newbie in cryptography.

Comment: use authenticated mode of operation like EAX, GCM. for details, see http://web.cs.ucdavis.edu/~rogaway/papers/eax.pdf, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode

Comment: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/16431/991 ​ ​

Answer (score 2):

I am going to answer my own question based on the comment from Ricky Demer: 
https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/16431/991

Given the attacker knew what the plaintext should be, for example:

```
{"userId":1}  --> this is knownText
```

And with the first approach, which was

```
aes-ctr((plaintext || sha2-256(plaintext)) || iv
```

Attacker can simply perform

```
(knownText || sha2-256(knownText)) XOR cipherText
```

To compute the AES cipher stream. Without having to know the key, the attacker can then compute:

```
(modifiedText || sha2-256(modifiedText)) XOR [deduced AES cipher stream]
```

Where modifiedText can be

```
{"userId":2}  --> I want to pretend to be user 2
```

and then append the original IV.

This would decrypt fine and also validates fine given the first approach. Hence it is insecure.