# What is the collision resistance of a 2048-bit hash based on SHA-3?

Tags: hash, algorithm-design, collision-resistance

Let $M$ denote the message. Let $B_i$ denote eight different bitstrings (chosen arbitrarily or randomly) such that $$0 \le \text{length}(B_i) \le 12345678.$$ Consider the following function (it outputs a 2048-bit hash of the input): $$H(M) = {H_1} \mathbin\Vert {H_2} \mathbin\Vert {H_3} \mathbin\Vert {H_4},$$ where $\mathbin\Vert$ denotes concatenation and $$\begin{array}{l}
{h_1} &= \text{SHA-3-512}({B_1} \mathbin\Vert M),\\
{h_2} &= \text{SHA-3-512}({B_2} \mathbin\Vert M),\\
{H_1} &= \text{SHA-3-512}({h_1} \mathbin\Vert {h_2}),\\
{h_3} &= \text{SHA-3-512}({B_3} \mathbin\Vert M),\\
{h_4} &= \text{SHA-3-512}({B_4} \mathbin\Vert M),\\
{H_2} &= \text{SHA-3-512}({h_3} \mathbin\Vert {h_4}),\\
{h_5} &= \text{SHA-3-512}({B_5} \mathbin\Vert M),\\
{h_6} &= \text{SHA-3-512}({B_6} \mathbin\Vert M),\\
{H_3} &= \text{SHA-3-512}({h_5} \mathbin\Vert {h_6}),\\
{h_7} &= \text{SHA-3-512}({B_7} \mathbin\Vert M),\\
{h_8} &= \text{SHA-3-512}({B_8} \mathbin\Vert M),\\
{H_4} &= \text{SHA-3-512}({h_7} \mathbin\Vert {h_8}).
\end{array}$$

Since all values of $h_i$ are the outputs of a simple MAC (which is [known to be secure enough](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/17928) for SHA-3) and all values of $H_i$ are taken by extracting one cryptographically secure 512-bit hash of two independent 512-bit bitstrings, I would expect that the collision resistance of $H(M)$ is close to 1024 bits of security. Is this assumption correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

It turns out that for a tree composition and concatenation of $n$-bit hash functions, [collisions can be found at $O(2^{n/2}\operatorname{poly}(n))$ cost](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F11799313_12).  So it still has pretty much 256-bit collision resistance.  The additional complexity buys you essentially nothing.

Note that 256-bit collision resistance is already *obscenely high*, against all plausible attackers (and there's no advantage even if you have a quantum computer); anything beyond it is completely meaningless.

Side note: If the adversary knows the $B_i$, the antiforgery property of a MAC, derived from the prefix-PRF $m \mapsto \operatorname{SHA3-512}(k \mathbin\Vert m)$, is not relevant.  If the adversary *doesn't* know the $B_i$, then this is not the scenario of collision resistance—but you're not going to get better than ‘512-bit security’ anyway, which is already (completely meaningless)^2.

Rather than worry about how to obtain (completely meaningless)^4 security levels from the *cryptography*, you should focus on writing a clear statement of your *application's* security model, making sure it's easy to audit and understand in the context of what you're trying to achieve, and making sure you've covered all possibly relevant threat models.

Comment: Thank you for the link! It's not that I worry about how to obtain 1024-bits security level, I am just interested in 
theoretical properties of a possible hashing construction.