# Can you use a dynamic key and data size for KMAC?

Tags: key-size, sha-3, encoding, kmac

I've [asked before](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/35127) if some kind of canonical encoding should be used on the input parameters of SHA-3 before it could be used as replacement for HMAC.

However, if I read the [current NIST specifications in NIST SP 800-185](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-185.pdf) correctly, there is no `Keypack` function defined. The `Keypack` function prefixed a key size to the key so that the key and message data are kept separate. Currently the key just seems to be zero-padded up to the next block boundary using the function `bytepad(encode_string(K), 168)` for KMAC128 and `bytepad(encode_string(K), 136)` for KMAC256.

Does that mean that there is no canonical encoding for key and data? Is it safe to use a dynamically sized key and data within KMAC so that `bytepad(encode_string(K), 136) || X != bytepad(encode_string(K'), 136) || X'` for `K != K`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, however it does take a deeper look into the standard.

KMAC128 is defined as:

> 1. `newX = bytepad(encode_string(K), 168) || X || right_encode(L)`.
> 2. `return cSHAKE128(newX, L, “KMAC”, S)`.

So there seem to be no encoding of the size of the key, which that there could be multiple K, M key message pairs that would result in an identical value of `bytepad(encode_string(K), 168) || X` (because `A || BC = AB || C`).

However if we take a look at the `encode_string(S)` function:

> 1. `Return left_encode(len(S)) || S`.

This means that the (bit) string encoding canonically encodes the key including the size of the key (`len(S)`). That means that any key with a different size will be encoded in such a way that the division between key K and message X is clear.

The canonical encoding is still present even though the `encode_string` has a more generic name compared to earlier KMAC drafts where it was called `Keypack(K, l)`  and took the length as explicit parameter.

Comment: Hmm, found the answer while creating the question, posted anyway, knowledge based style. The NIST notation is a bit of a compromise between text, pseudo-code and math if you ask me.

Comment: We have come a long way. I would be surprised if NIST could have done such a mistake.