# Using bcrypt for MAC - is it correct and secure?

Tags: hash, mac, sha-256, chosen-plaintext-attack, bcrypt

Suppose there is a hashing function:

$$ph = bcrypt(sha256(m + k), salt)$$

Here $ph$ is a password hash obtaining by applying $bcrypt$ on $sha256$ result of concatenating a message $m$ with a secret key $k$. Assuming that

1. key $k$ is not visible to attacker;
2. key is a "truly" random sufficiently large string;
3. the work factor of $bcrypt$ is sufficiently large as well;

The question is how much is this schema secure? Can an attacker obtain the secret key $k$ by issuing messages $m$ and retrieving hashes $ph$ and how much efforts will it take? How much does the strength of this schema depend on the size of the key?

Are there any ways to improve this schema?

I thought such schema may be used for MAC. Should I use `HMAC+SHA512` instead?

Comment: What would be the advantage over a normal MAC? HMAC is considered pretty secure (and KMAC for SHA-3 will likely share that property). You're missing the work factor in your parameters. `c` is not a ciphertext. A ciphertext is the result of encryption. This is a (password) hash result (some people may go for the *phash* term here). I don't think you can compare that with a IND_CPA as used for a block cipher based encryption scheme.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes thanks for your comment! I'll correct the question. What about HMAC.. Could you please describe disadvantages of my schema with the answer? If you want and able, of course. It may be helpful for others. May the schema be considered as secure with sufficiently large work factor? Fast signing of message is not required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The question is how much is this schema secure?

Not significantly more secure than `sha256(m + k)` [is](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2669/attacks-of-the-mac-construction-mathcalhmk-for-common-hashes-mathcal) and may be less secure. An attacker who could arrange a collision for that would trivially also get a collision for the bcrypt hash of that, regardless of the salt value.

While SHA-256 is collision resistant, there are MACs that have better bounds, like HMAC, which does not need to rely on the collision resistance of the hash. Using bcrypt like this when you already have a strong key is just a waste.

> How much does the strength of this schema depend on the size of the key?

As long as the key is at least 128 bits, it should be secure. It will not be much more secure even with a long key, due to the collision attack mentioned, and if the collision resistance of SHA-256 is ever broken then it may be insecure.

> Should I use HMAC+SHA512 instead?

That is one good alternative.

Answer (score 4):

Although your scheme is secure - especially with a random key of 32 bytes or higher - it won't offer any benefit over HMAC. It's therefore not recommended to use such a scheme.

Also note that `bcrypt has been designed for key stretching which is deliberately ***not*** efficient. You have ample entropy in your key so there is no need for key stretching.