# Differences between MAC and HMAC

Tags: hmac, mac

After reading many posts, I am still confused about the differences between these two.

Let me know if my understanding is correct:

MAC is encrypted string that is generated using a secret key and a message, and it's used to check no-repudiation.

HMAC is a MAC that is generated using a hash function and it's used to the check the integrity of the message.

Some questions below:

- Is HMAC an extra security layer over MAC?
- Should HMAC be always used instead MAC?
- In which scenario are both used? on TLS?

Comment: Apart from the last bullet, this is a duplicate of [What is the difference between MAC and HMAC?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/6523/18298) and in this form, this question is too broad.

Comment: Yes, I have already read that post before but I still don't know if my understanding is correct.

Comment: Short answer: HMAC is a specific way of building a MAC, much like an apple is a specific kind of fruit. So none of your questions really makes sense: Does an apple taste better than a fruit?

Comment: if you read that post, which was extremely clear, and still do not understand, I dont think we can help