# Is MAC-then-encrypt with stream ciphers secure?

Tags: mac, stream-cipher, authenticated-encryption, forgery

While thinking about [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/18292/why-is-mac-using-noncemessagehashnoncemessageidentifier-not-the-standard) recent question about a hash-then encrypt design, I reread the MAC-encrypt vs. encrypt-MAC question and noticed [this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/354/13625) quoting a paper showing that MAC-then-encrypt is secure with stream ciphers, even if not generically.

However, there's this attack when the MAC is deterministic and the cipher a stream cipher (or a block cipher in e.g. CTR or OFB mode, or even a OTP):

1. Assume the attacker knows the authenticated plaintexts of two different equal-length messages: $m_1||MAC(m_1)$ and $m_2||MAC(m_2)$.
2. The attacker intercepts the ciphertext of a third equal-length message: $E_k(m_3) = S_k(n) \oplus (m_3||MAC(m_3))$, where $S_k(n)$ is a unique keystream from nonce $n$.
3. The attacker can now modify the message in flight to $S_k(n) \oplus (m_1||MAC(m_1)) \oplus (m_2||MAC(m_2)) \oplus (m_3||MAC(m_3))$.
4. With a high probability, that is only a valid message when $m_3$ matches either $m_1$ or $m_2$, which the attacker could learn from whether the receiver e.g. asks for a new message (assuming corruption) or accepts it. If it *was* one of those two messages, it becomes the other instead.

This seems to both give the attacker information on the original message $m_3$ and allow them to forge communications.

Is there something wrong with the attack (e.g. did I assume too much) or is this just a lesser break than [the paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.106.5488&rep=rep1&type=pdf) (pdf) from that answer considers?

Comment: You assumed too much. $\:$ (There's really nothing else to say.) $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer, any specifics? E.g. is the problem 1. and that an attacker must never see authenticated plaintext? (Which implies the MAC key used in MAC-then-encrypt must never be used for anything else.)

Comment: The problem is 1; an attacker must never see authenticated plaintext. $\;$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As correctly pointed out in a comment, the authenticated encryption model assumes that

- the attacker knows the algorithm;
- the attacker can query the encryption oracle with any plaintext $P$ (and a unique nonce $N$) and get MAC-then-Encrypt ciphertext $C$;
- the attacker can query the decryption oracle with any string $C$ pretending to be a ciphertext.

No other data is available to the attacker. The assumption you made that the MAC alone is available is too strong.

Comment: Ok, I guess it makes sense as the formal model. Nevertheless, it seems like something a practical implementation could get wrong.

Comment: Yes. The MAC here is essentially an intermediate variable in the encryption procedure. A secure implementation shall never leak any intermediate variables.

Comment: That part should be known to all implementors, but the fact that you can't reuse the MAC to authenticate other (plaintext) strings is not the case with encrypt-then-MAC.

Comment: In your attack you do not reuse the MAC for other plaintexts.

Comment: $m_1$, $m_2$ could be any plaintexts authenticated with the same MAC key, they don't have to have been ever encrypted.

Comment: Yes, I mean that you do not reuse the same MAC value for another plaintext.