# Can I use `SHA (message || key)` as MAC?

Tags: mac, sha-2

One should not use SHA for MAC, because knowing `SHA(key || message)` and `message` you can construct `SHA(key || message || forgery)` without knowing the actual key. I read somewhere that one shouldn't use `SHA(message || key)` as MAC. Why? Here `||` means string concatenation.

Comment: Strongly related: [Why is MAC using nonce+message+hash(nonce+message+identifier) not the standard?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/18292/23623)

Answer (score 1):

If you know a length-preserving collision, that is, two distinct messages $M_1, M_2$ of the same length with $\operatorname{SHA}(M_1) = \operatorname{SHA}(M_2)$, then you know apriori that two messages $M_1 || \text{Pad}(M_1)$ and $M_2 || \text{Pad}(M_2)$ (where $\text{Pad}$ is the SHA padding function) will evaluate to the same value (and hence the MAC is broken).

This immediately shows that this MAC is insecure if instantiated with SHA-1.