# School exercise on untrusted channel comunication

Tags: hash, integrity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is H(k||x) not a secure MAC construction?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1070/why-is-hkx-not-a-secure-mac-construction)

I've the following problem:
two parties, A and B, share a secret key Kab.
M is a plaintext message, H an unkeyed hash function

A send to B `M, H( Kab | M )` (where | means concatenation).

If we want to provide data origin authentication and data integrity (no confidentiality required) my exercise states that we have to change the protocol to this:

A send to B `M, H( Kab | M | Kab )`.

I don't understand the difference in term of guarantees of the two protocols and thereby, why the second one is 'right' and the first one is not?

Comment: See: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1070/why-is-hkx-not-a-secure-mac-construction

Comment: Note that the exercise assumes that the hash in question is a Merkle-Damgaard hash without truncation; if the hash was (say) SHA-3 or SHA-2-384, $H( Kab | M)$ does appear to be sufficient.

Comment: Thank you. I supposed that the problem was with 'non-ideal' hash function. Now it's clear to me, thanks!