# Worth taking performance hit of HMAC to gain additional security?

Tags: hmac, sha-2, sha-512

It seems like SHA-512 truncated to 256 bits is usable as a MAC [[1](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/59997/58123)].  The advantage is that it's ~50% faster than HMAC-SHA-256 on 64-bit CPUs and ~50% faster than HMAC-SHA-512 on short inputs.  (My use case involves mostly short inputs.)

However, the HMAC construct provides an extra layer of protection in case of collisions in the underlying hash function [[2](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/187868/163855)].  This extra protection ended up being practically useful when weaknesses were found in MD5 and SHA-1.

Because of this, it seems better to use truncated HMAC-SHA-512 over truncated SHA-512.  Is that a reasonable (e.g. not-overly-paranoid) choice?

Comment: If we assume that [1] and [2] are true then HMAC-SHA-512 better choice.

Comment: I guess I'm wondering if truncated SHA-512 (with a prefixed secret key) might also be resilient in a similar way that HMAC is.

For example, if SHA-1-like weaknesses are found in SHA-512, will truncated SHA-512 (with a prefixed secret key) still be usable as a MAC?  Or will that also be similarly broken?

Comment: Very roughly, what is the proportion of computation time spent on your hash component, compared to the entire duration of the user experience/transaction?  The answer will determine whether or not this is an example of premature optimisation, therefore making the answer kinda moot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we assume that [1](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/59997/58123) and [2](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/187868/163855) are true then HMAC-SHA-512 is a better choice.

For the time comparison, as stated Paul Uzsak, if there is no specific time relevant problem around ~50% faster shouldn't be considered. If more secure, then use it.

**For your comment;**

The [shatter attack](https://shattered.io/) on SHA-1 requires a degree of freeness in the hashed data as in PDF's. This attack may or may not apply to other formats, but still, SHA-1 is considered broken and it is already non-standard, kick out.

With the [identical-prefix collision attack](https://shattered.io/) probably you cannot [forge](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/60640/18298) the MAC with this method. We haven't seen any complicated attack that uses the shatter attack to break some other constructions, yet.

The output of SHA-1 is 160-bit and it is in the generic birthday-attack range for our computing [powers](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/63537/18298), especially for a collective like bit-coin miners who reached $2^{91.6}$ SHA-256 hashes per year on 25 September 2018.

512-bit is not prone to generic collision attacks. This will require $2^{256}$ hashes to find a collision with probability 50%. For SHA-256, it is still impractical for today's standards $2^{128}$ and this is equal to brute-forcing AES-128 up to some constant.

When a new attack occurs for a hash function we have to look at it so that what the attack can be used when the hash function used in HMAC construction. However, as noted by the [Forest](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/187868/163855)

> In particular, an HMAC demands much weaker security guarantees from the hash function than many other applications it may have. It only requires **weak collision resistance** from the underlying hash.

**For the security case** You should be prepared to move into new standards. Even if there is not an attack to carry a collision attack into a HMAC construction, you should immediately move away from that hash function into more [secure one](https://www.csoonline.com/article/3256088/hacking/why-arent-we-using-sha3.html).

---

**note:** Weak collision resistance is the **second pre-image resistance**:

it is computationally infeasible to find any second input which has the same output as any specified input, i.e., given $x$, to find a 2nd-preimage $x' \neq x$ such that $h(x) = h(x')$.