# Security difference between $\mathrm{Keccak}(k\mathbin\|x)$ and $\mathrm{Keccak}(x\mathbin\|k)$

Tags: hash, hmac, keccak

$\require{begingroup}\begingroup
\DeclareMathOperator{\keccak}{\mathrm{Keccak}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\concat}{\|}
$According to [Keccak's website](https://keccak.team/keccak_strengths.html), $\keccak(k \concat x)$ is safe:

> Unlike SHA-1 and SHA-2, Keccak does not have the length-extension weakness, hence does not need the HMAC nested construction. Instead, MAC computation can be performed by simply prepending the message with the key.

My question is, is $\keccak(x \concat k)$ safe?

I read [Why is $H(k\mathbin\Vert x)$ not a secure MAC construction?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/1070) but I guess it doesn't apply to Keccak.
$\endgroup$

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See chapter 5.11.2 of the paper “Cryptographic sponge functions” (the link can be found [here](https://keccak.team/papers.html)):

> Note that one can also define a MAC function by taking as input the message followed
>   by the key: $t = \left\lfloor {F(M \mathbin\Vert K)} \right\rfloor _n$.  In this case, an adversary has the advantage that she can try
>   to generate inner collisions *offline*, i.e., without having to query the keyed sponge function. Additionally, she can try to construct a path to a state that occurs in the absorbing of a target
>   message, leading to a second message with the same MAC.

Comment: For an offline attack you would need to create a collision on the full 1600 bit internal state, a rather tall order. in case finding sha3 collision wasn't hard enough.

Comment: @MeirMaor: But $\text{Keccak-}f[b]$ permutations are defined for all $b \in \{25, 50, 100, 200, 400, 800, 1600\}$, thus the full internal state is not required to be always equal to 1600 bits.

Comment: SHA-3 only uses $b = 1600$, so Meir Maor's statement is about SHA-3, but the question was about Keccak in general. But if I understand the quote right, an **inner** collision is a collision in the capacity section of the sponge state, which I believe is sufficient to construct a full state collision (top of p. 17 for the linked paper on sponge functions).

Answer (score 5):

Keccak(x||k) is very likely secure, but it is less efficient than Keccak(k||x) for multiple messages.

The standardized MAC construction for use with Keccak is KMAC as defined in [FIPS 800-185](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-185.pdf). In KMAC, you first absorb the key *padded to the rate length of the sponge*. You can then copy the resulting Keccak state, and re-use it for all messages which will use the same MAC key.

With KMAC you don’t need to re-absorb the same key repeatedly for each message. This can make a significant performance benefit for MAC of many small messages (such as VPN packets).

In short: use KMAC.