# Does pepper *require* an HMAC?

Tags: hash, keys, hmac, passwords, password-hashing

Assume you are *already given* a properly-salted, password hash $X$ from some *slow* PBKDF (e.g., like Argon2id).

Now, you want to apply some large (~256-bit) secret "pepper" $S$ to it before storing it in the database.

Is there a significant difference between storing it as an
$$\text{HMAC}\left(S,X\right)$$ 
(where $S$ is the secret key to the HMAC of $X$) versus a *"much simpler/basic"*
$$H\left(S\mathbin\parallel X\right)$$

where $H$ is just some SHA-2? (e.g., SHA-256/512)

Comment: A related question [Why is H(k∥x) not a secure MAC construction?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/1070/18298). Since you are not interested in a forgery or length extension attack, both should be fine for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No for this scenario where the message is statically sized, using a HMAC is not required. You can use a sufficiently strong hash such as SHA-2 or SHA-3 instead if you *must*.

That said, it would probably be more neat to use a HMAC or even KDF. The advantage is that these algorithms do take input keying material as a separate parameter. This might be interesting if you want to keep the pepper secret; you could store it in a hardware device and use it for HMAC, for instance.

Currently you are using the hash as poor-man's KDF. So if you can spare a few cycles you might go for a more luxurious option like HKDF (which is based on HMAC).

Comment: I agree with the conclusion, but not with "statically sized" as the sole argument (I get it as: length extension does not apply). It is necessary to invoke that SHA-2 is a good enough hash that $X\mapsto H(S\mathbin\parallel X)$ is a good PRF keyed by $S$ for constant-size $X$. It would be possible to define a weak $H$ such that observing $X\mapsto H(S\mathbin\parallel X)$ leaks $S$, when that would not apply to $\text{HMAC-H}(S,X)$. That is, not using HMAC puts unduly pressure on the hash, and that pressure is not part of its explicit design criteria. HMAC is advisable for unspecified $H$.

Comment: @fgrieu once can use SHA256/224 or SHA512/256 etc. to mitigate from length extension attacks.

Comment: @fgrieu Sure, I put in a stronger hash requirement. You're theoretically correct of course, but the hash needs to be **really** weak for short, static, random content to become a problem in this scenario.